# When the slice element is removed, the original slice is broken

Tags: go, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // test data
    var a = [][]int{
        []int{1,2},
        []int{3,4},
        []int{5,6},
        []int{7,8},
    }

    for i := range a {
        fmt.Println(a) // print out
        _ = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...) // remove element
    }
}
```

expected result

```
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
```

actual result

```
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
[[3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [7 8]]
[[3 4] [7 8] [7 8] [7 8]]
[[3 4] [7 8] [7 8] [7 8]]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KahcX1MmDHO

why does this result? the original slice is broken. :(

Comment: You must never rely on the value you pass as a first argument to `append`. Its state is not deterministic, only what `append` returns is a reliable value.

Comment: Also in your loop you're not removing elements, you're simply copying the elements. Removing an element requires to assign the slice value returned by `append()`.

Comment: I wanted to keep the original slice and get the slice that was removed from certain values.

Comment: You cannot. If you want to keep the original, you must copy it explicitly as a separate operation, before you alter it.

Comment: Read an understand https://blog.golang.org/slices

Comment: What is the purpose of this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you re-slice you don't change the underlying array.  So the first time through your loop (`append(a[:0], a[1:]...)`) you create `a[:0]` which is a slice of len 0 (cap 4) pointing to the element 0 and `a[1:]` is a slice of len 3 (cap 3) pointing to element 1.

As @icza pointed out using `append()` in this way just moved the underlying array elements around.  For each loop iteration this happens:

0: elements 1-3 are moved to places 0-2

1: elements 2-3 are moved to places 1-2

2: element 3 is moved to place 2

3: nothing is moved since a[4:] has zero length

This gives the changed values that you see.

BTW Please post the simplest code which shows the problem. The nested slice is irrelevant.

```
func main() {
    var a = []int{1,2,3,4}
    for i := range a {
        fmt.Println(a)
        _ = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)
    }
}
```